# Cannot calculate with Pods Framework field return value

Tags: php, wordpress, pods-framework

Recently I started to work on Pods framework in Wordpress. In pods I want to add a shortcode that will calculate the rent of the house. But when I put the code in that shortcode, instead of picking up the value that the user put in the rent field, the code does not pick any value. It just returns null. Please help me with this.
Here's my code:

```
add_shortcode( 'calculate', function( $content ) {

    $prop = pods( 'prop', 338 );

    if ( $prop->exists() ) {
        $content = $prop->field( 'rent' ) + 100;
    }

    return $content;

} );
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: and what datatype is it?

Comment: the rent field is created in pods admin panel. I'm calling the field and it's value in this code.

Comment: It is a plain number field

Comment: function of what? The whole pod or the field?

Comment: @DaljitSingh. Can you post both?

Comment: What does `$prop->field( 'rent' )` return? Since you want to use the return value to do a calculation (+100), you should make sure that it's an integer or a float, ie. `floatval( $prop->field( 'rent' ) ) + 100`

Comment: @Michael I did that too but  then it is returning 0.

Comment: I tested your function and it works fine. Make sure `338` is the correct ID and that you don't get any other errors.

Comment: 338 is the correct id of my field. But I don;t know what's happening with my code.

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs He's talking about the [Pods Framework](https://pods.io/docs/code/).

Comment: @DaljitSingh You need to pass your Pod item ID to `pods()`, not your field ID.

Comment: @Michael I know it's a bit stupid question but I'm relatively new to pods framework and back-end programming, so can you tell me how can I find the pod item ID?

Comment: You can see it in the edit screen of your pod item: `?page=pods-manage-prop&action=edit&id=1`

Comment: I put the correct ID this time. Still no results.

Comment: I actually used Advanced Content Types for my test. If you created or extended custom post types, you might have to use the ID or the slug of your post type item.